# Does failure of cin makes failure in stdin?

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is trying to get an input even if user enters ctrl + D(EOF).
So I tried something like below.

```
while (true)
{
    if (getline(cin, str))
        break;
    else
    {
        cin.clear();
        //clearerr(stdin);
    }

}
```

I used cin.clear() to reset the failbit of cin when it met the EOF. But even if i used cin.clear(), my function didn't work. I knew that cin and stdin is syncronized and using same input buffer, so I thought that I should clear the error of stdin too. So I wrote clearerr(stdin). And Finally it worked.

Can I know the exact reason why I should use clearerr(stdin) too? I am just guessing now and can't find why.

Thank you

Comment: Interesting question. The precise effects of `std::cin` being synchronized with `stdin` are specified [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio). Note that this does not mention anything about recovery after errors, so I guess the behaviour is implementation defined. I'm waiting for someone with more expertise to answer but your approach seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I also cannot explain this, but I will note (building on comment by @john) that in my tests if I add `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` then `cin.clear()` is enough to get the desired behavior.

Comment: oh I also did try std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false); or something like cin.tie(false); but it didn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Well, if `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` makes it work for me (Ubuntu, GCC 9.4.0) but not for you, then that is a point towards this being implementation defined (I don't think any of this falls into undefined behavior).

Comment: Umm... I tried again. I write like this

std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
while (true)
{
    if (getline(cin, str))
        break;
    else
    {
        cin.clear();
        std::cout << feof(stdin) << std::endl; // it prints 1
    }
}

But it shows infinite loop. Isn't it?
and I am just using imac